# Video.JS Recommended Encoder Setting for Cell Streaming

Tags: ios, video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I'm on the final steps of finalizing a video.js heavy website and am running into one problem that I really don't want to leave to experimentation. I was wondering if there were any recommendations for streaming over 4G/3G.

The problem occurs specifically when streaming HLS using the hls-contrib tech over 4G/3G. Both Android (Lollipop) and iOS 9 phones immediately pick up audio but never get video, or do several minutes later (a normal user would stop watching by that point). When I plug in an Android or iOS device for console debugging, there are no console errors (symptoms persist), and turning on WiFi gets me both audio and video. Which leads me to believe I'm just dealing with an encoder settings problem here. Their signal chain is encoder (setting below) to a Wowza server, and out to ScaleEngine as a CDN. They're of course using the CDN HLS and RTMP links for public playback.

Encoder Settings:
Video: H.264 @ 1,250Kbps CBR, 720x480@30i
Audio: AAC @ 96Kbps Stereo
Profile: Main 
Level: 3.1
B-Frames: 0
Don't see any other pertinent info.

Appreciate the help/opinions/general information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Aaron did you get this sorted?

Comment: @BenClose No I never solved this. I went back and forth with my CDN and they claimed that it was perhaps because I was sending timing data (can't remember the official title that gets reported in ffprobe). I might run that again and post the output in my question. 

So for now I actually have a disclaimer below the player. Lame.